# Solving a PDE problem considering the nonlinear diffusion coefficient of Richards equation

Tags: fipy

I'm trying a very simple 1D simulation on Richards equation, simulating a soil column, with zero water pressure (Dirichlet boundary, u=0) at its base (left in 1D), and a rain (Neumann boundary, q=1E-5) at the top (right in 1D). In strong form,

[image]

The diffusion coefficient (k(u), or hydraulic conductivity) relies on water pressure (which should be negative all through the soil column due to capillarity). The variable z is the elevation from a reference point, here at the bottom (or left) of the mesh.

I coded the following script, but still can't figure out how to obtain results any close to the one I obtained using SEEP/W, a professional software solving Richards equation. I used a loop to recompute k(u) since it relies on u.

```
import fipy as fp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Simulation with professional software SEEP/W
seep = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/essicolo/e670981aa0171a449a554d7763157374/raw/8d06b07117f6f31a57b2156d07a2ba971a355e97/gistfile1.txt')

# Material parameters
alpha = 2.0 / 9.807  # [1/m]
n = 1.5
m = 1 - 1/n
l = 0.5
Ks = 1.0E-4  # [m/s]

# Top infiltration
rain = 5E-5

# Domain
nz = 200
Lz = 20.0
dz = Lz / nz
mesh = fp.Grid1D(nx=nz, dx=dz)

# Variables
z = fp.CellVariable(name="elevation", mesh=mesh, value=mesh.cellCenters[0])
u = fp.CellVariable(name="matrix pressure", mesh=mesh, value=-z.value)
u.setValue(u_min, where = z >= -u_min) # close to the real solution
u_old = fp.CellVariable(name="old matrix pressure", mesh=mesh, value=-u.value)
u_convergence = fp.CellVariable(name="convergence check", mesh=mesh, value=0.)
K = fp.CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=Ks)

# Boundary conditions
u.constrain(0., mesh.facesLeft) # bottom
g = fp.FaceVariable(mesh=mesh, value=-rain)
u.faceGrad.constrain(g * mesh.faceNormals, mesh.facesRight) # top

# Solver
max_iters = 100
tolerance = 1e-10
solver = fp.LinearLUSolver()

convergence = []
iterations = []
for iter in range(max_iters):

    plt.plot(u.value, z.value, label=f'Iter {iter}')
    u_old.value = u.value

    K.setValue(Ks * (1 - (-alpha * u)**(n-1) * (1 + (-alpha * u)**n)**(-m)) * (1 + (-alpha * u)**n)**(-m*l), where=u < 0)
    K.setValue(Ks, where=u >= 0)
    
    eq = (fp.DiffusionTerm(coeff=K, var=u) + K == 0)
    eq.solve(var=u, solver=solver)

    u_convergence.value = np.abs(u.value - u_old.value)

    iterations.append(iter)
    convergence.append(np.mean(u_convergence.value))
    
    if np.all(u_convergence.value < tolerance):
        break


plt.plot(seep['u'], seep['z'], c='k', label='with SEEP/W')
plt.legend()

#plt.plot(iterations, convergence)
```

Thanks for your time and support,

Essi

Comment: `u_min` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

```py
fp.DiffusionTerm(coeff=K, var=u) + K == 0
```

isn't your equation.

Just as you have [image: 1D derivative] in 1D, in multiple dimensions:

[image: multi-dimensional derivation]

where [image: unit vector] is the unit vector in the z direction.

I find that

```py
eq = (fp.DiffusionTerm(coeff=K, var=u) + (K.faceValue * [[1]]).divergence == 0)
```

behaves more like your SEEP/W result, although it's hard to be sure without knowing what `u_min` is.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback . I tried the equation you suggested, and while the pressure profile improved, it still doesn't match my two analytical benchmarks. The expected pressure should decrease, then stabilize at a certain depth. However, the FiPY solution seems influenced by the column height (Lz). Also, the initial guess affects results significantly: with an initial guess of 0.0, all u values remain zero. I've tried different solvers, but results are similar. Suggestions to improve my gist code would be appreciated! https://gist.github.com/essicolo/57cb63cc6fe5c3f93da1a91c9b8a8a8f

Comment: Comments are not suited to back-and-forth discussion. Please either revise your question or take this to https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/discussions.